# How to store more than 1600 column in postgresql

Tags: python, xml, pandas, postgresql

I am storing very large samples data-set which is necessary to store on pgadmin, however it accepts only 1600 columns. I have stored it in pandas dataframe right now. Is there any way to store it in pgadmin for my django application?

I thought to partition dataframe in small xml files with id mapping, but am not sure how to do that and how to query afterwards from such database.

Any kind of insight or guidelines regarding storage, will be much appreciated.

Comment: You should properly normalize the data.

Comment: you could melt the columns but you'd end up with a very large dataframe.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe , I wish I could do that but It's in most normalized way. Each column has data about different individuals.

Comment: If each column represents different individuals then as normalized it would transform each column into an individual row; as it is it's repeating data.

Comment: @Belayer , You are right but, I have 58k rows and 19k columns. Rows also represent unique quality of each individual stored in columns. So transforming it to rows also won't help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could segment the data into multiple tables with common primary keys.

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
  id uuid PRIMARY KEY,
  -- 1599 more columns
);

CREATE TABLE table2 (
  id uuid PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES table1 (id),
  -- 1599 more columns
);

CREATE TABLE table3 (
  id uuid PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES table1 (id),
  -- 1599 more columns
);
```

etc.

Any analysis is just an INNER JOIN away.